# Greedy Initialization in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, initialization, greedy

I'm currently coding up a feed-forward network in Tensorflow and I want to make a custom initializer which initializes each layer using a (externally defined) function of the point with the highest MSE.

**Pseudo-code:**

```
 Given any input data being passed to my current layer:

 - Identify datapoint *X* with highest MSE from target
 - Initialize at *f(X)*
```

Sorry if I posted no pseudocode but I have *absolutely no idea* how to go about it in Keras (Python not R).

Comment: Do you mean to say that you want the Weights of your Neural Network to be updated in such a way that it Maximizes the MSE of the Output Layer, because Initialization is one time but Updating the Weights is Continuous throughout the Training.

Comment: Basically, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want your `Weights` to be updated with respect to `Maximized Loss` rather than `Minimized Loss` (from the comment), it can be achieved by passing `-loss`, as shown in the code below:

**Tensorflow Version 2.x**:

```
loss = tf.keras.losses.MSE()
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss = -loss)
```

**Tensorflow Version 1.x**:

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.keras.losses.MSE(y_true, y_pred))
trainm = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(-loss)
```

Hope this helps.